# Issue saving card for customer

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I would like to store credit card information for a customer in our QuickBooks account
using the PHP Payments SDK - the following is what I am trying to achieve this but I get an invalid arguments error:

```
$client = new PaymentClient([
'access_token' => $accessTokenValue,
'environment' => "sandbox" ]);


$array = [
   "number" => "4408041234567893",
   "expMonth" => "12",
   "expYear" => "2026",
   "name" => "Test User",
   "address" => [
       "streetAddress" => "1245 Hana Rd",
       "city" => "Richmond",
       "region" => "VA",
       "country" => "US",
       "postalCode" => "44112"
    ],
    "customerid" => "94"
];


$create = CardOperations::createCard($array);
$response = $client->charge($create);
```

I have not had any luck reaching out to support, any way this can be done, I appreciate the help.

**Error received:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> QuickBooksOnline\Payments\Operations\CardOperations::createCard() must
> be an instance of QuickBooksOnline\Payments\Modules\Card, array given

**UPDATE using recommended code:**

> Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
> QuickBooksOnline\Payments\Operations\CardOperations::createCard(), 1
> passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error it seems the required Card data should be an instance of the class

```
QuickBooksOnline\Payments\Modules\Card
```

But you're passing array to it. As per the documentation could you please check this below code , hopefully it will work.

```
$client = new PaymentClient([
    'access_token' => $accessTokenValue,
    'environment' => "sandbox" 
]);
    
    
$cardData = [
    "number" => "4408041234567893",
    "expMonth" => "12",
    "expYear" => "2026",
    "name" => "Test User",
    "address" => [
        "streetAddress" => "1245 Hana Rd",
        "city" => "Richmond",
        "region" => "VA",
        "country" => "US",
        "postalCode" => "44112"
    ],
    "customerid" => "94"
];

$chargeData = [
  "amount" => "10.55",
  "currency" => "USD",
  "card" => $cardData,
  "context" => [
        "mobile" => "false",
        "isEcommerce" => "true"
    ]
];
$customerId = "94";

$charge = ChargeOperations::buildFrom($chargeData);
$chargeResponse = $client->charge($charge);

$clientId = rand();
$card = CardOperations::buildFrom($cardData);
$createCardresponse = $client->createCard($card, $clientId, rand() . "abd");

//or alternatively $createCardresponse = $client->createCard($card, $customerId, rand() . "abd");
```

Comment: Hi Ishaque, please see my updated post, it now says I am not passing all parameters - to create card. Please refer to this library I am using, https://github.com/intuit/PHP-Payments-SDK/blob/7e96b081afa8c092814ab041ebc41b80e90809f9/src/PaymentClient.php#L174

Comment: The error I get is: `Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function QuickBooksOnline\Payments\Operations\CardOperations::createCard(), 1 passed`

Comment: just pass the another parameter $create = CardOperations::createCard($card,$customerid);

As per your example data it will be $create = CardOperations::createCard($card,94);

Comment: @StephanieSmith please check I have also updated my answer if it's correct marked is correct answer or upvote it. Thanks

Comment: I now get the following error: `Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function QuickBooksOnline\Payments\Operations\CardOperations::createCard(), 2 passed in and exactly 4 expected in quickbooks/payments-sdk/src/Operations/CardOperations.php`

Comment: It is referring to this file in the SDK - please take a look: https://github.com/intuit/PHP-Payments-SDK/blob/7e96b081afa8c092814ab041ebc41b80e90809f9/src/Operations/ChargeOperations.php

Comment: @StephanieSmith please check I have updated my answer .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241693/discussion-between-ishaque-javed-and-stephanie-smith).

Comment: Thank you for the help